# Как совместить свои HTML макеты метки и ObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Здравствуйте!

Намереваюсь в json-описание меток ObjectManager записать свой html-шаблон:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature", 
            "id": 0, 
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", 
                "coordinates": [
                    55.831903, 37.411961
                ]
            }, 
            "properties": {
                "balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна", 
                "clusterCaption": "Метка с iconContent", 
                "hintContent": "Текст подсказки", 
                "iconContent": "1"
            }, 
            "options": {
                 "iconLayout": ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><div class="square_layout">1.5M</div></div>'),
                 "iconShape": {
                    "type": "Rectangle",
                    "coordinates": [[-25, -25], [25, 25]]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Однако, возникли затруднения. При попытке загрузить объект на карту возникает ошибка:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token y in JSON at position 411

Понятно, что после ключа "iconLayout": должно идти значение (value) в кавычках. Да и вообще так делать некошерно, поскольку нельзя передавать функцию в файле с данными.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решилось добавлением своего preset:

```
ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('my#default', {
        iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><div class="square_layout">$[properties.iconCaption]</div></div>'),
    });
```