# Свои метки API яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть json-массив с координатами. описанием и т.д. Что написать вместо tutzatyk чтобы отображались свои метки?

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [

        {"type": "Feature", "id": "geoid_1", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.22253553, 44.91619948]}, 
                "properties": {"balloonContent": "", "clusterCaption" : "Еще одна метка0", "hintContent": "Текст1 подсказки"}},

        {"type": "Feature", "id": "geoid_2", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.22775721, 44.93772153]}, 
                "properties": {"iconImageHref": "/assets/img/16.gif", "balloonContent": "", "clusterCaption" : "Еще одна метка1", "hintContent": "Текст2 подсказки"}},

        {"type": "Feature", "id": "geoid_3", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.23167024, 44.86977306]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "", "clusterCaption" : "Еще одна метка2", "hintContent": ""}, 
                "tutzatyk" : {"iconLayout": "default#image", "iconImageHref": "/assets/img/16.gif", "iconImageSize": [30, 42], "iconImageOffset": [-5, -38]}}

    ]
}
```

Comment: посмотрите этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772722/Как-совместить-свои-html-макеты-метки-и-objectmanager
и пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager

Comment: options - работает

Comment: если вопрос решен, вы можете добавить ответ, который вам помог)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо написать options вместо tutzatyk

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите `options` вместо `tutzatyk`.

Например:

```
{"type": "Feature", "id": "geoid_3", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.23167024, 44.86977306]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "", "clusterCaption" : "Еще одна метка2", "hintContent": ""}, 
                "options" : {"iconLayout": "default#image", "iconImageHref": "/assets/img/16.gif", "iconImageSize": [30, 42], "iconImageOffset": [-5, -38]}}
```

Comment: А чем ваш ответ отличается от уже принятого ответа топикастера?

Comment: С более подробным примером.